# Where does the negative for this u-substitution come from?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I am trying to integrate the problem below and was going to start off by substituting u for wt. I got really stuck somewhere along the way so I looked it up using the integration calculator and from step 1 it's different. I did u=wt but apparently, you're supposed to do u=-wt? Can someone explain where the negative sign comes from? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: You can do it either way.  Maybe the extra minus sign puts it into a specific form desired for some other reason.

Comment: @Randall thank you for your comment. yes it does seem to be like that looking through the steps, but how would one know to do that beforehand? or is it just something you'd have to do with trial and error? and how is one able to just add a negative?

Comment: *how is one able to just add a negative?* Two different paths to the same destination.  *but apparently, you're supposed to do u=-wt?* No, using $d=wt$ is equally valid and likely as useful.

Comment: @ryang ahh gotcha okay thank you. I figured it out.